# Azure mobile services Not Found error with .net backend

Tags: c#, azure, windows-phone-8, azure-mobile-services

I've created new mobile service with .net as backend. Now when I try to run the sample WP8 project that I downloaded from the portal. It gives me the error "The request could not be completed.  (Not Found)". 
This is the request object

```
{Method: GET, RequestUri: 'http://barbini.azure-mobile.net/tables/Product', Version: 1.1, Content: <null>, Headers:
{
  X-ZUMO-INSTALLATION-ID: cc027ec3-b2ec-4445-b8a3-50a601a2fb39
  X-ZUMO-APPLICATION: fdArvxSstsNLSZaIPIKFoGkHXxvwHcY36
  Accept: application/json
  User-Agent: ZUMO/1.0
  User-Agent: (lang=Managed; os=Windows Phone; os_version=8.0.0.9903; arch=Win32NT; version=1.0.20402.0)
  X-ZUMO-VERSION: ZUMO/1.0 (lang=Managed; os=Windows Phone; os_version=8.0.0.9903; arch=Win32NT; version=1.0.20402.0)
}}
```

And my product class is as follows

```
[Serializable]
public class Product : ModelBase
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The id.
    /// </summary>
    private string id;

    /// <summary>
    /// The name.
    /// </summary>
    private string name;

    /// <summary>
    /// The price.
    /// </summary>
    private double price;

    /// <summary>
    /// The is active.
    /// </summary>
    private bool isActive;

    /// <summary>
    /// The product group.
    /// </summary>
    private ProductGroup productGroup;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the id.
    /// </summary>
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id
    {
        get
        {
            return this.id;
        }
        set
        {
            this.id = value; 
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("Id");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the name.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The name.</value>
    [JsonProperty("name")]   
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return this.name;
        }
        set
        {
            this.name = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the price.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The price.</value>
    [JsonProperty("price")]   
    public double Price
    {
        get
        {
            return price;
        }
        set
        {
            this.price = value; 
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("Price");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the is active.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The is active.</value>
    [JsonProperty("isactive")]
    public bool IsActive
    {
        get
        {
            return isActive;
        }

        set
        {
            this.isActive = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("IsActive");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the product group.
    /// </summary>
    [JsonProperty("productgroup")]
    public ProductGroup ProductGroup
    {
        get
        {
            return this.productGroup;
        }

        set
        {
            this.productGroup = value; 
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("ProductGroup");
        }
    }

}
```

I even tried to remove https and made it simple http. But still the error persists.
Can anyone help where I m going wrong

Thanks

Comment: have you published your backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a "table" in the .NET backend of mobile services you need to both define the entity type which you'll use (in your case, `Product`), and also create a class which derives from `TableController<T>`. The generic parameter (`T`) in that class must implement the `ITableData` interface, and the easiest way to do that is to make the class inherit from the `EntityData` class. For example, this would give you a "product" table in your service:

```
public class ModelBase : EntityData, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // implementation of INPC omitted
}

public class Product : ModelBase
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The name.
    /// </summary>
    private string name;

    /// <summary>
    /// The price.
    /// </summary>
    private double price;

    // other properties omitted for brevity

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the name.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The name.</value>
    [JsonProperty("name")]   
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return this.name;
        }
        set
        {
            this.name = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the price.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The price.</value>
    [JsonProperty("price")]   
    public double Price
    {
        get
        {
            return price;
        }
        set
        {
            this.price = value; 
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("Price");
        }
    }
}

public class ProductController : TableController<Product>
{
    protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(controllerContext);
        var context = new TheContextClassInYourService(this.Services.Settings.Schema);
        this.DomainManager = new EntityDomainManager<Product>(context, this.Request, this.Services);
    }

    public IQueryable<Product> GetAll()
    {
        return base.Query();
    }

    public SingleResult<Product> GetOneProduct(string id)
    {
        return base.Lookup(id);
    }

    // insert
    public Task<Product> PostProduct(Product input)
    {
        return base.InsertAsync(input);
    }

    // update
    public Task<Product> PatchProduct(string id, Delta<Product> patch)
    {
        return base.UpdateAsync(id, patch);
    }

    public Task DeleteProduct(string id)
    {
        return base.DeleteAsync(id);
    }
}
```